# Component in vhdl for hold,load and shift

Tags: vhdl

I have a few questions related to this problem:[image]

So I need to implement this in VHDL in structural mode.The given resource has to be able to do a loadX, loadY,shift and hold and change lsb to 1.(so mode should be on 3 bits-5 modes)  I know that I need to use components but I'm stuck to what type of components I should use. Otherwise I would've implemented this as a shift register. Any small help would be great.I'm new to VHDL. I'd post code but as I said I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, Well you can define loadX and loadY as input pins and an output port.

```
entity resourceB is 
port (
modein : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
loadX : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
loadY : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
loadO : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end resourceB;
```

since you need to perform a shift operation depending on the type of mode then I believe you need to make use of a `case` statement. But then since you need to change the lsb to 1, you might also need a temporary register to do it.

```
Architecture behave of resourceB is 

signal temp_r, temp_d, temp_q : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):= (others => '0');

begin

process(clk, reset)
begin 

if(reset = '1') then 
temp_q <= (others => '0');
elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then 
temp_q <= temp_d;
end if;
end process;

loadO <= temp_q;

process(modein, loadX, loadY)
begin 

case modein is 

when "000" => temp_d <= loadX <some shift operation> loadY;
              temp_d(0) <= '1';
when "001" => temp_d <= loadX <some shift operation> loadY;
              temp_d(0) <= '1';
when "010" => temp_d <= loadX <some shift operation> loadY;
              temp_d(0) <= '1';
when "011" => temp_d <= loadX <some shift operation> loadY;
              temp_d(0) <= '1';
when "100" => temp_d <= loadX <some shift operation> loadY;
              temp_d(0) <= '1';

end case;
end process;
end behave;
```

" *some shift operation* " can be either of the shift operations which is upto you and you need to fill in that part.

**NOTE: The above code might have some bugs in it, but I wrote that based on my understanding from your problem description.**